# Can I also create a layout like this using Lazy Column? (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

Can I also create a layout like this using Lazy Column? Do you have any useful data? 
The layout I want is to fill it up without any empty space.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can use:
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-staggered-grid

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
    columns = StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(200.dp),
    verticalItemSpacing = 4.dp,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
    content = {
        items(randomSizedPhotos) { photo ->
            AsyncImage(
                model = photo,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().wrapContentHeight()
            )
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```